# Difference Between Mouse and Key events ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

So I'm having a bit of a problem handling a situation. I have an application, which is an MDI application, which opens custom documents. My MDI parent has a ToolStrip, with a few controls, a text box and a button. The text box holds a qty value for an item, then there is a button to add the item to the document. the model for fastest operation is, starting with the qty text box, enter the qty, tab to the part number text box and enter the part #, then tab to the add button and hit either enter key or space key. This is way faster than using the mouse to click the button, or click to enter the text box. So I want my app to auto focus the qty text box once the button is fired.

I've handled the ToolStripMenuItem.Click event, which adds the item, and then refocuses the qty box, and it works perfectly when the mouse is used to click the button. But for some reason I've yet to discover, this does NOT work for when the keyboard  triggers the button. I know the click event is being triggered, because the item gets added properly, but the focus is not handled correctly. In fact, in this case, it seems the focus is just lost completely, tab ceases to function, focus can't be regained except with the mouse. I've tried the following:

1. Call Form.Activate() i the parent form, and handle the Activated event to focus the text box.
2. Call Focus() on the parent form, and handle the GotFocus event to focus the text box.

It's as if the underlying framework fails to properly handle key events, and there are no Key events exposed for the ToolStripMenuItemButton control. I'm sort of at a loss. The app is functional, as the mouse works, and the app can actually be used, but for best functionality I need to get this working so that fast data entry can be done without the use of the mouse.

Comment: There shouldn't any difference between both situations as far as the given event is called. I see two possible problems here: either you are doing something in another event which is not triggered in both cases (for example: KeyUp not triggered by the mouse); or the click event is not reached in both cases (and you are saying that this is not happening...). In any case, it is always better to take a look at the code, please, post the relevant parts.

Comment: @varocarbas -- I have validated his issue by creating a simple test example.  For some reason, the ToolStripButton class does not have any keyboard-related events.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your situation (certainly weird, no doubt); although the answer you got does not seem to deliver an always working solution (some times work, some times not), but perhaps this is the best thing you have...

Comment: @roryap as said in the comment above; no idea about this weird situation. Just a couple of clarifications: I didn't suggest to use any key-related event, just wrote an example of what might be a sensible explanation for the problem (but, apparently, no sensible explanation: just pure weirdness); I tested your code and, as expected (as far as refers to Form events), is not 100% accurate (I have +1ed you anyway), it depends upon what the user has selected (the form or not). In the OP's position, I would do some tests to come up with a for-sure working solution.

Comment: @varocarbas I'm curious as to what scenario you were able to see this solution NOT work? If you found one I'd like to know so I can address it. It seems to work sufficiently for me. If I do encounter a problem with it in the future I'll have to figure out. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ah! If it works for you, excellent! But for me works just some times; actually, every time I do something does not work. My exact conditions: new project with a ToolStrip containing two buttons and one textbox; if I click on the textbox, press the tab key until getting the button I want and I press enter, the proposed solution does not work. Initially, it was working but, honestly, now I am not even able to re-simulate these conditions. The basic idea behind this correction and what makes it work or not is that you have to select the form, if you don't do that, the correction is not triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that is a weird behavior.  I was able to overcome it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool myButtonJustClicked = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myButtonJustClicked = true;
        toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(myButtonJustClicked)
        {
            toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
            myButtonJustClicked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm using the form's "KeyUp" event to handle the KeyUp event that *should* be fired on the button but there is no "KeyUp" event, or any keyboard-related events, for some reason on ToolStripButtons.

In order to make sure that the textbox doesn't get the focus when other KeyUp events fire elsewhere in the form, I use the myButtonJustClicked boolean as shown.

Also, I left the `toolStripTextBox1.Focus();` in the `toolStripButton1_Click` method to handle the mouse click, of course.

Comment: Glad to help.  BTW, you should check out Martin Carolan's EventSpy: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11918/EventSpy.  It helps you figure out what events are firing in situations like this.  I registered it on the Form, the ToolStrip, and the button, and that's how I realized the Form's "KeyUp" event was firing after everything else.

Comment: What's even stranger, is that the original process works as intended when debugging. I think maybe it has something to do with the debug process causing the threads to take longer for certain events outside the breakpoints being able to fire off before the focus() gets done.

Comment: @Wanabrutbeer .NET is pretty reliable but when it makes weird things, they are really, really weird :) So, I suggest you to not waste time on intending to come up with an explanation (it is just a kind of bug which, presumably, will be there for quite a while), but on validating your solution thoroughly; as said in the comments above: this is not 100% accurate and you will have, most likely, to complement it with further corrections.